# How to get offsetTop at first loading in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get a elements offsetTop. But it will be undefined.

How can I get it? I checked mdn.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

But I couldn't find how to do it.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const dividers = document.getElementsByClassName("divider");

  const offsets = [
    dividers[0]?.offsetTop,
    dividers[1]?.offsetTop,
    dividers[2]?.offsetTop,
    dividers[3]?.offsetTop
  ];

  console.log("dividers", dividers);
  console.log("offsets", offsets);

  return (
    <>
      <p style={{ height: 200 }}>aaaaaaaaa</p>
      <div className="divider">
        _______________________________________________
      </div>
      <p style={{ height: 200 }}>bbbbbbbbb</p>
      <div className="divider">
        _______________________________________________
      </div>
      <p style={{ height: 200 }}>cccccccccccc</p>
      <div className="divider">
        _______________________________________________
      </div>
      <p style={{ height: 200 }}>ddddddddd</p>
      <div className="divider">
        _______________________________________________
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the Codesandbox.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stoic-proskuriakova-kzl2iq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: ... `  useEffect(() => {
  const offsets = [
    dividers[0]?.offsetTop,
    dividers[1]?.offsetTop,
    dividers[2]?.offsetTop,
    dividers[3]?.offsetTop
  ];
  console.log("dividers", dividers);
  console.log("offsets", offsets);
  }, [])` ...?

Comment: Yeah. I could do it. Thanks. Also I wanted to use the return's result. And  I got the answer.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Array and fill to make it less repetitive and to be able to set the ref's indexes dynamically instead of hardcoding. [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-booth-0ix5xi?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [offsets, setOffsets] = useState();
  const ref = useRef();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const dividers = document.getElementsByClassName("divider");
    setOffsets(dividers);
  }, []);
  console.log(offsets);

  return (
    <>
      {offsets && (
        <>
          <p style={{ height: 200 }}>aaaaaaaaa</p>
          {offsets[0]}
          <div ref={ref} className="divider">
            _______________________________________________
          </div>
          <p style={{ height: 200 }}>bbbbbbbbb</p>
          <div ref={ref} className="divider">
            _______________________________________________
          </div>
          <p style={{ height: 200 }}>cccccccccccc</p>
          <div ref={ref} className="divider">
            _______________________________________________
          </div>
          <p style={{ height: 200 }}>ddddddddd</p>
          <div ref={ref} className="divider">
            _______________________________________________
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is ref for?

Comment: @user42195 ref is completely useless here and you can't store more than one element inside the same ref (unless it's an array and you're indexing them correctly). Also, your goal is to simply calculate the offsets of each element?

Comment: Yeah. My goal is getting the offsets of each element. Thank you for letting me know about ref. :) I will study about it deeper.